# How can I force Mobile Vision for Android to read full lines of text?

Tags: android

I have implemented Google's Mobile Vision for Android by following a tutorial. I am trying to build an app that will scan a receipt and find the numeric total. However, as I scan different receipts that are printed in different formats, the API will detect TextBlocks in what seems to be an arbitrary way. For example, in one receipt, if several words of text are separated by single spaces, then they are grouped into a single TextBlock. However, if two words of text are separated by lots of spaces, then they are separated as independent TextBlocks, even though they appear on the same "line". What I am trying to do is force the API to recognize each entire line of the receipt as a single entity. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far As I know: No, You cannot configure the detection and recognition in any way.
Its native part (libocr.so) uses a neural network which is trained to find blocks (or lines and Words) in a certain way.

What you can do if you have a closer look to the API: any `Word`, `Line` or `Block` has coordinates attached to them. You will have to check their coordinates and determine if they are considered to be the same line (take into account that the picture of it might not be aligned properly).

This will probably not work for all receipts in the same way, so you may also implement different search heuristics for different receipts.

Comment: Thanks ... 
Is there no solution for this taking an example


total                          500
this is the total amount


now if I scan this using mobile vision then it will return two TextBlock one containing  "total this is the total amount" and another "500".  But  I need 500 to be displayed after total i.e. "total 500 this is the total amount"

Comment: There is a solution. You have to create a custom implementation for it. No out of the box solution for your very specific problem